# PHP code optimize, Maximum allowed memory error

Tags: php, laravel

I try to make my code more reusability. However, I'm not very familiar with PHP. I would like to discuss the code with you guys.

Basically, the `post_data` is part of the `record_student`. The reason I split it is because I have others similar function to do the curl posting. Therefore, I make a curl function for reuse in others function. The code below will be facing the `maximum allow memory` issue. I'm not sure which part goes wrong.

```
public function record_student()
    {
       $url = $this->get_url();

       //foreach function to handle the data

       $this->post_data();
    }
public function post_data()
    {
            $data = $this->sync_sale();
            $curl = curl_init();

            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    // Set here requred headers
                    "Api-key: " . Input::get('api_key'),
                    "accept: */*",
                    "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
                    "content-type: application/json",
                ),
            ));

            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            Debugbar::info($response);
}
```

Comment: How many times do you call this method and how large is each `$response` on average?

Comment: where is the `post_data()` function obtaining the value of `$url`? Either declare `$url` as a parameter to `post_data` or as a `global` within

Comment: @apokryfos There have only 12 records so it will be called 12 times. I'm not sure how large the `$response` but I only posted name,id and date. It working fine if I didn't split the function to two

Comment: it might be useful to show us the version that works fine and the version that causes a memory issue.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment I made I can see no reference to `$url` within `post_data` other than when it is called ~ unless the code posted above is not the actual code you are running? Provide the url as either a named parameter or  declare as a global variable within thge function body or make it a global property of the class by setting `$this->url=$this->get_url();` and using `$this->url` within the curl function.

I modified the two below methods to reflect the named parameter approach and added some additional debugging code which often provides really useful info for curl requests ~ though I made an assumption that `Debugbar::info` can be used to display info to screen/file.

```
public function record_student(){
    $url = $this->get_url();
    $this->post_data( $url, true ); # call method with named parameters
}

public function post_data( $url=false, $debug=false ){
    if( $url ){

        $data = $this->sync_sale();

        if( $data ){

            $curl = curl_init();
            if( $debug ) $vbh = fopen( 'php://temp', 'w+' );

            $options=array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    "Api-key: " . Input::get('api_key'),
                    "Accept: */*",
                    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
                    "Content-Type: application/json",
                ),
            );

            /* enhanced debugging info if in debug mode */
            if( $debug && $vbh ){
                $options = array_merge( $options, array(
                    CURLOPT_VERBOSE     =>  true,
                    CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS  =>  true,
                    CURLOPT_STDERR      =>  $vbh
                ));
            }

            curl_setopt_array( $curl, $options );

            $response = curl_exec( $curl );
            curl_close( $curl );


            if( $debug && $vbh ){
                /* process info captured in the temp stream */
                rewind( $vbh );
                $verbose = stream_get_contents( $vbh );
                fclose( $vbh );

                /* assumed that Debugbar::info will print data somewhere */
                Debugbar::info( $verbose );
            }


            Debugbar::info( $response );
            return $response;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try closing the curl request with `curl_close`.

Comment: I did but still the same

Comment: what are you doing on sync_sale and get_url? they might be leaking memory

Comment: did you also try ```unset($response);```, after the log?